# Typescript - Generic implementation

Tags: typescript

I could define an interface for object equality like:

```
interface IEquatable<T> {
    readonly equals: (x: T, y: T) => boolean
}

const stringEquatable: IEquatable<string> = {
    equals: (x: string, y: string) => x === y,
}

const numberEquatable: IEquatable<number> = {
    equals: (x: number, y: number) => x === y,
}

stringEquatable.equals("hello", "world") // false
stringEquatable.equals("hello", "hello") // true

numberEquatable.equals(1, 2) // false
numberEquatable.equals(1, 1) // true
```

But I could also shortcut the implementation of `stringEquatable` and `numberEquatable` like:

```
interface IEquatable<T> {
    readonly equals: (x: T, y: T) => boolean
}

const strictEquatable = {
    equals: <T>(x: T, y: T) => x === y,
}

const stringEquatable: IEquatable<string> = strictEquatable
const numberEquatable: IEquatable<number> = strictEquatable

stringEquatable.equals("hello", "world") // false
stringEquatable.equals("hello", "hello") // true

numberEquatable.equals(1, 2) // false
numberEquatable.equals(1, 1) // true
```

Coming from a csharp background, I'm confused as to what the following line is doing

```
const stringEquatable: IEquatable<string> = strictEquatable
```

I expected that implementing `IEquatable<string>` would require an implemenation of `equals` that closes over the `string` type, however `strictEquatable` has a generic implementation.

What typescript feature is making this possible?

Comment: you can do it by using `string|number`, such as ```const strNumEquatable: IEquatable<string|number> = strictEquatable```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question what does `const stringEquatable: IEquatable<string> = strictEquatable` is nothing, or at least nothing special. It's just a simple assignment, the more inserting question is why is the type of `strictEquatable` compatible with `stringEquatable`

Typescript, unlike C#, has a structural type system. This means that the compiler will figure out the compatibility of types base on their structure. In the case of generic functions this means that the generic version of `equals` is compatible with a function signature where `T` is set a specific type. Lets consider a simified version of your code:

```
const genericFn = <T>(x: T, y: T) => x === y;
const stringFn: (x: string, y: string) => boolean = genericFn; // valid for T = string
const wrongReturnTypeFn: (x: string, y: string) => number = genericFn; // error
```

The reason the type system works this way is that types are erased at compile time and we are left with plain old JavaScript which does not care about what type the arguments to the function are or what generic parameters the function had in typescript.